# Filter rows from today in MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql

I use this query to filter out rows from different day than today. I need to get only column `book_url`:

```py
"""
SELECT book_url
FROM KNIHY
WHERE  CAST(KNIHY.scrape_date AS DATE) = CAST( curdate() AS DATE)
"""
```

where `scrape_date` has a following form `29/12/2021 07:13:21`.

My code fails on `mysql.err.ProgrammingError`. How can I fix it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are storing text dates in the `scrape_date` column.  You should instead be using a proper bona fide date column here.  In lieu of this, you may try converting the text to date using `STR_TO_DATE()`:

```sql
SELECT book_url
FROM KNIHY
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(scrape_date, '%d/%m/%Y') = CURDATE();
```

Comment: thanks, are you sure there should be `%H:%i:%S` instead of `%H:%M:%S` ?

Comment: `%i` means minutes, `%M` is the full month name (e.g. January, February, etc.).  Yes, I'm certain that my format mask is correct for your text date.

Comment: unfortunately it does not work, see my edit please.

Comment: The logic is fine, [check this demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ead192fd78069d076cddcfa3eedf1f25) to convince yourself.  Your data may have some other problem.

Comment: Thanks for demo. I create the column using  `scrape_date TEXT`, could that be a problem?

Comment: Good question, I don't know.  What is the exact problem or error you are seeing in your Python script?  That is the best place to start trying to figure out what might need to change.

Comment: I do not get any error, I just return empty tuple after i execute this querry and call `self.cursor.fetchall()`. It seems like the condition `WHERE STR_TO_DATE(scrape_date, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%S') = CURDATE();` does not meet anything, which is nonsense. There are rows from today in KNIHY

Comment: Gotcha! `WHERE STR_TO_DATE(scrape_date, '%d/%m/%Y') = CURDATE();` just edit your answer and I will accept it, thanks :)